# preg_match won't return the row but detects it (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Here's my code:

```
            $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://comic.naver.com/webtoon/detail.nhn?titleId=570506&no=99&weekday=thu");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1");
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

 $matches = array();
        preg_match('/^.*\bcontent_image_0\b.*$/um', $result, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

var_dump($matches);
```

I added /um in the end because the charset on the website is UTF-8.

What I want it to do is to find the row that contains "content_image_0" and return the whole row.

This is what var_dump($matches); dumps:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(383) "   " [1]=> int(25958) } }
```

We can see that it detects 383 strings but does not return them, the quote is empty :/

Comment: The pattern is good, but you don't see the result because the html tags don't appears in your browser. So right click and display the page source. Or use `echo htmlspecialchars($matches[0][0]);` to display the string in your browser, or `echo htmlspecialchars(print_r($matches, true));`

Answer (score 0):

To capture a match (that's different than the entire match) you need to use a capturing group, indicated by parens `()`, around the data you want to capture. For example, to capture the entire line:

```
preg_match('/^(.*\bcontent_image_0\b.*)$/um', $result, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

To capture and return all 383 matching rows / lines, you need to use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) with a capturing group per line which you can do as follows:

```
preg_match_all('/^(.*\bcontent_image_0\b.*)$/um', $result, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the capturing groups like this:

```
preg_match('/^(.*\bcontent_image_0\b.*)$/um', $result, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
              ^---      here       ---^
```